# Is pressure only due to weight?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

Consider a closed bottle on earth's surface. The pressure at its bottom is atmospheric pressure. Although the height of of air column in the bottle is very less the pressure is still the same probably because the air molecules inside the bottle have adjusted their velocity (increased it) so that the pressure inside the bottle gets equal to the outside.
Considering the bottle to be unbreakable.

Question

1. Why does the pressure need to be equalized? Why do the molecules inside increase their velocity (if that happens )? Is it because they are getting a force from outside? But why does the pressure get equal? Why not more or less?
2. Then the total pressure should be the sum of  that due to the weight of the molecules ( since there is gravity) and that due to their velocity.
   If you say its one and the same then can $P=h\rho g$ be shown equal to $P=1/3\rho v^2$?
   ( if there is no gravity the first part goes!)

Answer (score 2):

There is no “adjustment” which occurs when or after the bottle is closed. The absolute pressure, and the distribution of velocities of the air molecules inside the bottle, will be the same as outside the bottle — as if the bottle did not exist around that region of gas.

---

Suppose the bottle is open (with the opening facing up) and things are at equilibrium. Then we know the pressure inside the bottle is the same as the pressure outside the bottle (at equal heights), because if it wasn't there would be a net flow of air molecules to correct it.

Now put the cap on the bottle. This means we have placed a barrier between the air inside the bottle and outside the bottle. But we have not actually changed anything by doing so — we did not compress the air inside the bottle (except possibly by an insignificant amount depending on the design of the cap).

Therefore, the absolute pressure is again the same. If the pressure were *not* the same on the two sides of the cap, then we would feel a force resisting putting the cap on. If you look at kinetic energies and individual gas molecules, “there is no net flow” (when open) translates into “the molecules outside and inside strike the top and bottom of the cap, respectively, with equal numbers and velocity” (when closed).

---

There isn't really a ‘shorter air column’ inside the bottle. The air column model is useful for understanding how *atmospheric* pressure comes about, but for a small container the gravitational effects are totally insignificant and you can just think about pressure by itself.

But if you want, you can say that, yes, there is a shorter column inside the bottle — but still at the original atmospheric pressure. Therefore, *if* it were free to move like the atmosphere is, it would rapidly expand to lower pressure, but it isn't, in two individually sufficient ways:

- If the bottle is open, then the pressure of the “short column” is opposed by the pressure of the remaining tall column of atmospheric air above it.
- If the bottle is closed, then the cap of the bottle is holding in the pressure.

  - If the bottle remains where it is, then the pressure on each side of the cap is equal (at least until the weather changes) and so it is under no net force and merely preventing mixing of otherwise-identical air.
  - If we transport our bottle into a vacuum chamber or up a handy space elevator, then the surrounding pressure is now zero, but the pressure inside the bottle is *still the same* — but because the *balance* of pressures and therefore forces has changed, the bottle is now at risk of breaking if it is not strong enough.

Comment: Llike op has said , if we take the bottle in space then there is no air outside but still the pressure inside the bottle is the same. That certainly means that the air inside the bottle has adjusted its pressure to earlier atmospheric one .This can be done only by increase in the velocity of the molecules since there is no air outside but pressure is the same as on earth.

Comment: @Shashaank Before you took the bottle to space, the pressure inside the bottle was _already_ equal to atmospheric pressure. The only change that happens at that time is the bottle walls reacting to the now-unbalanced pressure — if they are not sufficiently rigid, the pressure in the bottle will _decrease_ as the volume expands.

Comment: No , I meant that according to the question , if the bottle is here on earth and it's closed then the pressure inside it is atmospheric. Now if taken outside in space the pressure inside it is still the same but there is no outside atmosphere to cause it by exerting it's weight or any thing like that. That pressure then has to be due the velocities of the molecules. That implies that at the surface of earth the molecules had attained that pressure which can only be by a change in the average velocity (change w.r.t to the air out of the bottle).

Comment: sort of like in the last paragraph of your answer !!

Comment: @Shashaank The pressure is _always_ “due to the velocities of the molecules”, and the outside atmosphere is _already_ at that same average velocity. Lowering outside pressure doesn't increase inside pressure, just increases the pressure _difference_ (sometimes called gauge pressure). (I've edited my answer to try to clarify.)

Comment: But then we say that the atmosphere weighs such and such. Gravity causes it to weigh. Since its weighs it has a 'weight ' pressure. You can probably say that this weight pressure is itself due to colliding molecules (velocity part). Isn't it ? Ok ! What will you say , if I ask you that whether the average velocity of molecules inside the closed bottle the same or grater than those outside .

Comment: @Shashaank I have already said that the average velocity was the same. Simple principle: Closing a container (without also compressing it) does not have any effect on the contents if they were at equilibrium already!

Answer (score 2):

Does your bottle contain anything other than air? If it is a closed, unbreakable bottle, why do you assume that its pressure will be equal to the atmospheric pressure? (or are you defining that in your thought experiment?)

I think pressure is fundamentally related to molecular motion, and only indirectly to weight. Pressure can be exerted in zero gravity when warming up a balloon; the gas molecule travel more quickly, and impact the inner surface of the balloon at higher velocity, this with more kinetic energy, this with more force, thus with more pressure. I see no weight involved in that scenario.

Let's consider a scenario where weight appears to be involved, such as a column of a fluid in a container (I suppose this is you scenario). At the bottom of the column there is a certain pressure, given by the height of the column and the density of the fluid (and yes, the gravitational constant). But what is really going on? The molecules are moving, impacting that bottom surface...

Let's assume our container contains water and air. Why do the water molecules impact the bottom more than the top? They are also acted in by the gravitational force I suppose, which draws them downward. Gravity draws the water downward more strongly than it draws the air, because the water is "heavier". Perhaps there is a situation where one molecule of the liquid is lighter (less mass) than one molecule of the "air" gas. What we observe as humans is the *bulk* effect, so it is not the masses of single molecules that really matters but the mass of the bulk substance, which relates to its molecule by its density.

Either way, gravity directs the water downward, so the molecules tend to have more collisions with the bottom of the container than with the air in the container or the top of the container.

The pressure at the bottom surface is not due to gravity directly, but due to the collisions of the molecules with the surface; the molecules are (on average) directed toward the "bottom" by gravity, so more collisions occur there than at a higher surface. This higher pressure. Gravity plays a role in these scenarios, but it is not required for pressure to exist. Particle motion is required to produce pressure.

Oh yes, and pressure can produced by light particles, "massless" photons!

Answer (score 1):

**Pressure is caused by containment**, and not weight per se, but weight or gravity causes containment, so, in a way, weight can be said to generate pressure.
When weight initiates pressure though, unlike other containments, there is a gradient in pressure by height.

And, **once generated, pressure can remain there as long as containment is there**.

This can be proven by imagining enclosing the earth with a shell $30$ km in height from earth's surface, and then turning off gravity.
The atmosphere will retain its total average pressure, but the gradient will be gone.

That's how pressure in a small bottle remains equal to $1$ atm even if we seal it from all sides, and take it to outer space.
The **adjustment** you talked about is more in terms of number of molecules than their velocity. The number of molecules both inside and outside are equal and that's why the pressure is equal.

---

###### How Does Gravity Generate Pressure?

The following discussion assumes that there is enough gravity so that air molecules don't have escape velocity at normal temperatures.

In the presence of gravity, momentum of every air molecule increases as it moves downward. This means that every molecule, say, in layer A, would feel more force when it was hit from above than when it was hit from below. **This would gradually move the molecules of layer A downward until a stage is reached when this effect is cancelled** by there being more molecules in the lower layer.

This means that the density of lower layers is more in the presence of gravity, which, in turn, means that the pressure becomes more as we descend. This is how gravity (or weight) generates pressure with a gradient.

(An interesting thing to note is that this model of molecules bouncing in a layer generates a downward force that is equal to the combined weight of the molecules in that layer plus of those above it!
Otherwise it was possible to pay less for a can of talcum powder by shaking it vigorously before taking it to the counter and then showing it is lighter than what the label says.)

This is somewhat similar to how pressure will be generated if in space, we start pushing in the piston of a cylinder (filled with air and closed at other end).

In both the cases above, once we have generated the pressure, if we

1. turn off gravity (while maintaining the containment using a shell), or
2. we stop moving the piston (but hold it there),

the generated pressure will remain.

---

###### Why does the pressure need to be equalized?

If we mix water dyed with different colors, why do the colors mix? It's the same thing happening here. Because there are more randomly moving molecules in a region than its vicinity, there will be an equalization. This is because of entropy and the second law of thermodynamics.

---

###### Can $P=h\rho g$ be shown equal to $P=1/3\rho v^2$?

$P=h\rho g$ is not true for a compressible gas with varying density (such as atmosphere).

The formula that is actually true and that results in $P=h\rho g$ for constant $\rho$ is $\frac{dP}{dh} = -\rho g$.
Both these formulae ($\frac{dP}{dh} = -\rho g$ and $P=1/3\rho v^2$) are true separately, and, interestingly $P=1/3\rho v^2$ can be shown to yield $\frac{dP}{dh} = -\rho g$ in the presence of g (see below).

**So no, these formula cannot be shown equal.**

---

###### Bonus

The kinetic formula $P=1/3\rho v^2$ yields the hydrostatic formula $\frac{dP}{dh} = \rho g$. Use $\rho$ from eqn. (7) [here](http://pirila.fi/energy/kuvat/barometric_derivation.pdf) assuming T (and v) = constant. We get: $$
\begin{align}
\frac{d\rho}{dh} &= -\rho \frac{gm}{kT} \\ 
\implies \frac{dP}{dh} &= \frac{1}{3}v^2\frac{d\rho}{dh} \\ 
&= \frac{1}{3}v^2 \times (-\rho \frac{gm}{kT}) \\ 
&= - \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{3kT}{m} \times \rho \frac{gm}{kT} \\ 
&= -\rho g
\end{align}
$$